# Vue update data from table

Tags: vue.js

I have below code

```
   <a-table :dataSource="data" :columns="columns" :pagination="false">
            <span slot="rate" slot-scope="rate">
              <b-form-input type='number' v-model="rate"></b-form-input>
            </span>
   </a-table>
```

Data is set as below

```
data() {
    return {
      columns: [
        {
          title: "Data 1 ",
          dataIndex: "group",
        },
        {
          title: "Data 2",
          dataIndex: "rate",
          scopedSlots: { customRender: "rate" },
        }
      ],
    };
  },
```

How I need to update the value of rate. How can i get the value in my handle submit function?

Comment: if you change rate object, b-form-input will be update. Because vue js use MVVM pattern

Comment: May I have sample? @RamilAliyev

Comment: please check these examples : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html